# Escaping special characters in javascript in a link

Tags: javascript, php

Not sure if I'm asking the right question. But this is what I want:
I have this code:

```
$content = rawurlencode(file_get_contents("c://Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$user."/".$file));
$thelist .= "<li class=files><a href=javascript:alert('".$content."') class=filelink>".$file."</a></li>";
echo $thelist;
```

What I want is to alert *(actually this is just a test, I want to use the `$content` as argument in a function)* the `$content` when I click the link. How should I do this?

I'm guessing it would work fine if the file is a simple txt file. But the file I'm using here is a C++ program, which contains characters <>, obviously

Comment: It's hard to tell what you *really* want to do, based on this 'alert' example. But you'd probably need either encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent().

Comment: @Arnauld not sure how I'm really going to do that haha the code is in php. As you can see I tried using rawurlencode(), i've also tried urlencode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get the file contents. This is pretty straight forward, except that you need to make sure that `$user` and `$file` don't contain any unexpected characters, such as `"../"` that would take you outside of the designated directory. Example using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (!preg_match ('/^[\w\d]+$/', $user) ||
    !preg_match ('/^[\w\d]+$/', $file)) {
  /* Error */
  return;
}
$content = file_get_contents("c://Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$user."/".$file);
```

Next, you need to turn the contents into a valid javascript string. To do this, you need to escape the **backslash**, **double** or **single** **quote** and **line terminator** characters (including **U+2028** and **U+2029**). I believe the easiest way to do this is using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$code = json_encode ($content);
```

The code (after the `javascript:` part) is technically a URL so it has to be escaped with [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php):

```
$href = 'javascript: ' . rawurlencode ("alert ($code)");
```

The `href` (and also the file name) then needs to be suitably escaped with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to be used as an HTML attribute. I think this can actually be skipped for  `$href` because the string is HTML-safe after `rawurlencode()`

```
$href_h = htmlspecialchars ($href);
$file_h = htmlspecialchars ($file);
```

Now we are finally ready to output the result. I like using [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) when mixing variables with HTML:

```
echo <<<_
  <li class=files><a href="$href_h" class=filelink>$file_h</a></li>

_;
```

Comment: Omg! You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much! That's all I can say. Haha mind blown